# How return to specific statement in main function from another class

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

I have a couple of nested methods in some class. First of them is called from main function. Now, if some condition is true,  I want that next executed statement is some statement in main . How do that?

```
class A {
      void a()
        {
            b();
            c();
        }
        void b()
        {
            e();
            c();
        }
 }
```

If some condition in any function in class A is true, I want go  to main function in class B, exactly on statement that is first after calling A.a()

Comment: Could you please provide a code sample? Also, my first reaction is: you can't, but maybe I fail you understand what you're trying to achieve...

Comment: Can you show some code that illustrates what you're trying to accomplish?  (Even non-compiling pseudo-code?)  It's not clear what you mean.  It sounds like you just want to return from the first method.  If that's the case, just use the `return` keyword.

Comment: Sounds like you want to pass a delegate as parameter. But some code would be helpful.

Comment: Quite the assumption @ken2k; if I were to be so ignorant - I'd assume that based on the juniority of asking 'how to return to main function', OP is rather new to such principles and is probably talking about basic coding. I think we're all having an 'educated' guess at what you mean here OP, please post some code or, at least, provide a reworded explanation.

Comment: As you can tell from the answers so far, anybody can guess as to what you need.  However, if you can post a code sample, we might be able to come up with more targeted advice.

Answer (score 0):

Use Goto *identifier*

Where Identifier is the point where you want to return to in main

Comment: Wow, I didn't even know `goto` existed in C# until just now.  I don't recommend its use for controlling the flow of execution, though.

Comment: I know not quite the solution, but the solution he asks warrants it

Comment: That answer is correct in terms of doing what you asked for.  (Downvoting stamhaney is not really fair per se).  However, goto is almost never a good idea.  Take a look at some of the discussion here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/46586/goto-still-considered-harmful

Comment: Ok guys just a suggestion, can remove it :)

Comment: another joke, can goto traverse across functions. That is i guess the intention of OP.

Comment: `goto` can traverse time and space.

Comment: I tried goto before posting question here, and it doesnt't work. I get error that such label is not in goto scope.
And I am not sure that goto can jump to label in another class.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to execute something in main based on a `function` then use `Func<bool>`, if your function takes in a parameter then use `Func<T in, bool>`.

**Usage**

```
  var isInt2 = new Func<int, bool>(int i => i == 2);
  if (isInt2(2))
    Console.WriteLine("Do something in main");
```

After your lambda `=>` you do your condition. The above is an example of `Func<T in, bool>`.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549151.aspx

Comment: Pretty sure the outside function isn't where the boolean should come from, but he may want to use delegates here.  My interpretation is that he wants to pass an `Action` from main to this class, which will come up with a boolean from...somewhere, and if true will call that action.